# NSUser Defaults save button status and display again

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I am new to iphone development. I am developing an app in that i am displaying some contact name with uncheckmark image. Once user taps the button to selected means i am storing it in an nsuserdefaults. Here is the code what i have tried.Actually my problem is another user value will change dynamically.I am adding one boolean value for all the users who are coming in the tableview. If an one more person is added in the another user i want to show in off state. For other users i have to store the values stored in nsuserdefaults. First time i am manually looping 0 in total user.

```
My interface File
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>    
NSArray * test;
IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;
IBOutlet UIImageView *photo;
IBOutlet UILabel *userName;
NSMutableArray *dataArray;
NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary;
NSMutableArray * selected;
NSUserDefaults *prefs;
NSMutableArray * statusArray;
NSMutableArray * prefsArray;

}
 @property(nonatomic,retain)    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *customCell;
 @property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
  @property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
 @end


implementation file:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
dataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
selected=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
prefs=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
prefsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


NSMutableArray * anotheruser=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"da",@"kn",@"gn",@"Prd",@"Kai",@"Sh",nil];
for (int i=0; i<anotheruser.count;i++) {
    [selected addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
}
for (int i=0; i< anotheruser.count; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setValue:[anotheruser objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"name"];
    [dict setValue:[selected objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"checked"];
    [self.dataArray addObject:dict];
}

[super viewDidLoad];
 }
    (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:NSInteger)section
  {
   return dataArray.count;
   }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
 {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = customCell;
    self.customCell = nil;

}

photo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"raj.jpg"];
NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
userName.text= [item objectForKey:@"name"];

[item setObject:cell forKey:@"cell"];

BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];
UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.frame = frame;   // match the button's size with the image size

[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.accessoryView = button;

return cell;
}
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
[self tableView: tblView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
[self.tblView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

    - (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
  {
  NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:tblView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
if (indexPath != nil)
{
[self tableView:tblView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
}
 }


   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
NSMutableDictionary *item = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
BOOL checked = [[item objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue];

NSUInteger myInt=indexPath.row;
    [item setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:!checked] forKey:@"checked"];

UITableViewCell *cell = [item objectForKey:@"cell"];
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;


if (!checked)
{
    [selected replaceObjectAtIndex:myInt withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
}else{
    [selected replaceObjectAtIndex:myInt withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
}

 [prefs setObject:selected forKey:@"status"];
   NSLog(@"%@", selected);
   UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] : [UIImage  imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
 [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

For CustomCell use like below..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    MyViewCell *cell = (MyViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    // MyCustomeCell *cell = (MyCustomeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];//custom cell
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (MyViewCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
            
        }
}
```

and for DefaultCell use bellow code...

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *kCustomCellID = @"MyCellID";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCustomCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCustomCellID] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    }
}
```

Comment: really cant understand what your trying to say

Comment: @Ranganathan you want to save the array in userdefault.. right?? then you can save the array in userdefault globaly with my above code.. now understand dude..??

Comment: I can save the array in nsuserdefaults. its not my problem

Comment: also see this link for more info about NSUserDefaul http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

Comment: 0- Off state.
1- on state
i have three elements in an array for example: xxx,yyy,zzz
I am adding a 0 to new users.
Initailly they will be in off state {0,0,0}
 If i have already some users in tableview. for first time they will be in off state. If user modifies the state of this three users it changes to{1,0,1}.I am storing this value in nsuserdefaults. I have to display this state in tableview for users. If one more element is added i have to maintain this status and i also want to add 0 to new users.
then my stored array in nsuserdefaults might be like this
{1,0,1,0}.

Comment: have u understood the what is my problem ??

Comment: yes i think u want to show the checked user with checkmark when you come back to another view right??

Comment: Yes I have to show the state maintained in nsuserdefaults and I have to show unchecked(O) to incoming new element in an array

Comment: @Ranganathan notreuse the cell its happen bcoz your indexpath.row is appear with reuse number of cell so try with my code ... and if you have a .m and .h file of your custom cell then tell me i post code related ur requirement dude.. :)

Comment: @Ranganathan see the final UPDated Code  dude.. sorry i just find this whole code from my app and now see the code... i hope you got ur output dude...

Comment: @Ranganathan you have a MyViewCell is object of UITableVieCell??

Comment: @Ranganathan    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = customCell;        
    } try this code instead of your code...